# Using ANT, identify if its EJB2 or EJB3

Tags: ant, build, ejb-2.x

We have a build server which is today building ejb2 and ejb3 applications but we now have a requirement to identify if a given project is a EJB2 or EJB3 then based on that we need to perform some validations.

Can anyone let us know how can this be done using ANT tasks or what is the logic to identify this ?